# Complex grouping algorithm with combinations in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, grouping, combinations

I have a complex grouping problem. I should solve it on Sql server 2005 but a solution that works on a more recent release is ok (we will upgrade soon).

test table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testGrouping](
[Family] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Person] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[transNr] [int] NOT NULL,
[Amount] [numeric](6, 2) NOT NULL,
[ExpectedGroup] [int] NULL
    )
```

test data

```
INSERT INTO [testGrouping]([Family],[Person],[transNr],[Amount],[ExpectedGroup])
SELECT       'f1','p1',1,  10.00,1
union SELECT 'f1','p1',2 , -9.00,1
union SELECT 'f1','p2',3 , -1.00,1
union SELECT 'f2','p3',4 , 50.00,2
union SELECT 'f2','p4',5 ,-50.01,2
union SELECT 'f2','p5',6 ,-30.00,3
union SELECT 'f2','p5',7 , 20.00,3
union SELECT 'f2','p5',8 , 10.00,3
union SELECT 'f3','p7',9 , -1.00,4
union SELECT 'f3','p7',10, -2.00,4
union SELECT 'f3','p7',11, -6.00,null
union SELECT 'f3','p9',12,  2.00,null
union SELECT 'f3','p7',13,  3.00,4
union SELECT 'f2','p6',14,100.00,null
```

Now the problem. The ExpectedGroup starts at null, I must fill it with my code.

The requirement is to identify groups of records with ABS(sum(amount)) <= 0.01
In details:

- I can group 2 or more records of the same "person";
- After grouping by persons, I can search groups in the same "family"
- Each record can belong to 1 group only
- Each person can belong to 1 family only
- Records that cannot be grouped have group = null
- A group can have more than 2 records (and that's the real challenge!)
- In the real data each "Family" can have up to 200 records, and each "Person" can have up to 10 records.
- Amount is always <> 0

Explanation of grouping in sample data:

- **Group 1**:
  Include all the records of family f1 because no partial combination of person in that family has ABS(sum(amount)) <= 0.01
- **Group 2**:
  Persons p3 and p4 have ABS(sum(amount)) <= 0.01.
- **Group 3**:
  Persons p5 has ABS(sum(amount)) <= 0.01. So Family f2 is divided into 2 groups and a single record (transNr 13) has no group
- **Group 4**:
  In family f3 you could group transNr 9 and 11 but there is a group that belongs to Person p7 only, therefore it has higher priority.

I could easily find groups like Group 1

```
select family, sum(amount) from testGrouping group by Family HAVING ABS(sum(amount)) <= 0.01
```

and also group 3

```
select person, sum(amount) from testGrouping group by Person HAVING ABS(sum(amount)) <= 0.01
```

But other cases are trickyer (see Family f2: there are several ways to construct groups there, grouping by p5 is trivial but the other records are not so easy)

My idea in pseudo code is:

```
-- process the easy cases...
group by person, set a group number to persons having ABS(sum(amount)) <= 0.01
group by family, set a group number to families having ABS(sum(amount)) <= 0.01 

-- process the remaining records
For each person
  Generate all combinations of not grouped records of that person 
  For each combination of records
    IF ABS(sum(amount)) of the combination <= 0.01 THEN
       Assign a group to records of the combination
       Recalculate the combinations (we have less records to work with)
    END IF
  Next combination
Next person

For each family
  Generate all combinations of not grouped records of that family 
  For each combination of records
    IF ABS(sum(amount)) of the combination <= 0.01 THEN
       Assign a group to records of the combination
       Recalculate the combinations (we have less records to work with)
    END IF
  Next combination
Next family

(on each step I can use only record not assigned to a group in previous steps, the For each translates into cursors)
```

My questions are:

- Can you suggest me a better algorithm? (the solution must be SQL only but to describe it pseudocode is ok) I think that my pseudocode translates into a spaghetti code of nested loops, cursors, goto and other ugly code.(performance is not so critical, a few minutes to process about 10.000 records is acceptable)
- How can I implement the "Generate all combinations" part? In the sample, for family F2 I should try all the possible groups of 2 records, then all the possible groups of 3 and so on till testing all the combinations. transNr is unique record ID.

Comment: please add expected output as well for the above sample data

Comment: Yep, having expected output would be helpful. It's really hard to understand A/C.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and I suspect your problem is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness). This means that if you have more than a trivial amount of data, it is unlikely you'll find an efficient solution.

Comment: Actually expected output is the field Expectedgroup. It starts null and must be filled by sql. The actual values do not matter provided that the records of each group have the same values in order to identify the groups.

Comment: PaulF, thanks for pointing out. I read the article and yes it is a subset sum problem. My fault I did not know the proper name for this.

Comment: @Luca: 1st question: You wrote transNr 13 has no group. I think you are actually referrring to transNr 14 as transNr 13 is within f3. 2nd question: In group 4 - f3 you wrote p7 has a higher priority. Do you mean transNr 9 and 11 cannot be grouped because transNr9 was already used in the group over 9,10,13? I do not fully understand the "higher priority" part of your question.

Comment: You are right about the mistake 13-14. By priority I mean that I must search for possible groups by person. After making all possible grouping by person I can start grouping by family only record without groups. Anyway @PaulF correctly identified the problem. We actually implemented a simpler solution with some heuristics that might miss some group but ends in a reasonable time. This is good enough for our actual need. Anyway I am curious about how a subset sum can be actually implemented in SQL.

Comment: I think the fourth line counting from the bottom should belong to group 4 and not null.